# firebase Real-Time Database to List View?

Tags: java, android, firebase-realtime-database

[image: Database]

Is there a way to retrieve all the child nodes to a textView?, i wanted to create a users log where you can tract what kind of transactions users have made, but i can't figure out how to get the nodes, and its list of children.

the code so far:

```
database = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance();
    String uid = FirebaseAuth.getInstance().getCurrentUser().getUid();
    reference = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference().child("Users").child(uid).child("Logs");
btn1.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {

            reference.addValueEventListener(new ValueEventListener() {
                @Override
                public void onDataChange(@NonNull DataSnapshot datasnapshot) {
                    String uid = FirebaseAuth.getInstance().getCurrentUser().getUid();
                    String logs = datasnapshot.child(uid).child("Logs").getValue().toString();

                    tv1.setText(logs);
                }

                @Override
                public void onCancelled(@NonNull DatabaseError error) {

                }
            });
```

Comment: Can you please provide the code or what you have tried?

Comment: How is `reference` initialized?

Comment: @FrankvanPuffelen sorry about the duplication of post sir, can you check the edited post?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're attaching a `ValueEventListener` to path `/Users/$uid/Logs` in your database, so the `datasnapshot` in your `onDataChange` contains the information for that node and any data under it.

When you then try to get the value of `datasnapshot.child(uid).child("Logs")` from that data snapshot, there is not child `$uid/Logs` in `datasnapshot`, so the value is going to be `null`.

---

To get the value for all the logs, you can

```
datasnapshot.getValue()
```

This will return a `Map<String, Object>` that you can then loop over.

---

Alternatively, you can loop over all the logs by date, and then by time, and print the value of the `Date` property for each, that'd be something like:

```
reference.addValueEventListener(new ValueEventListener() {
    @Override
    public void onDataChange(@NonNull DataSnapshot datasnapshot) {
        for (DataSnapshot daySnapshot: datasnapshot.getChildren()) {
            Log.d("Firebase", dateSnapshot.getKey());
            for (DataSnapshot timeSnapshot: daySnapshot.getChildren()) {
                Log.d("Firebase", timeSnapshot.getKey());
                Log.d("Firebase", timeSnapshot.child("Date").getValue(String.class));
            }
        }
    }
    ...
```

To learn how to then show this in a list view or a recycler view, I recommend searching for that: https://www.google.com/search?q=how+to+show+data+from+firebase+in+a+list+view